# How to extend a reference class defined in an R package that uses private functions?

Tags: r, class, oop, reference-class

Following on from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452112/how-to-extend-a-reference-class-defined-in-an-r-package), I would like to be able to allow users to extend a class in my package *which uses private (not `export`-ed) functions*.

A minimal working example:

```
# my_package/R/Main.R
# My package:
#' @import methods MASS
PrivateFunc <- function(...) fractions(0.5)     # a private function

#' @export Main
#' @exportClass Main
Main  <- setRefClass("Main",
    methods = list(
        initialize = function(...) PrivateFunc()
    )
)
```

Problem is, the `Main` class uses functions that are *not* exported from `my_package`, such as `PrivateFunc`, and also `fractions` from package `MASS` which is an `Import` rather than a `Depends`.

Thus as soon as I instantiate an class that extends `Main`, R complains about not being able to see `PrivateFunc`:

```
library(my_package)
Child <- setRefClass("Child", contains = "Main")
Child()
# Error in .Object$initialize(...) : could not find function "PrivateFunc"
```

Does this mean that I am forced to `export` every private function used by `Main`? Would this not severely pollute the global namespace (precisely the reason why I use `Imports` over `Depends)?

So how best to fix this?

**Edit**: Also, there is the possibility that the user may chose to extend `Main` from within their own package that they are writing

Comment: If I type this all at the command line, just as a test, the `PrivateFunc` gets called - twice - when you **define** the `Child` class. Put a `print` in with the `fractions` call and you'll see it. I don't understand R's class system sometimes...

Comment: @Spacedman - it is for the same reason that `Main` must not contain any mandatory parameters in the `initialize` method. Try changing `Main` to have `initialize = function(x) force(x)` -- you won't even be able to *define* `Child`, regardless of how you intend to instantiate it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of reference classes. I suggest checking out R6 (note that I'm the author). See the documentation links at the bottom of the [project page](https://github.com/wch/R6). The upcoming version has an option called `portable`, which allows for cross-package inheritance without any trouble.